# How to build template dynamically in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have JSON object data:

```
let data = {
    id: 1,
    name: "Block1",
    fields: [{id: 1, fieldType: "input"}, {id: 1, fieldType: "table", sourceUrl: "http://"}]
}
```

This object can contain over 100 `fields` elements.

I need to build HTML view template based this template.

I did first step, when I iterate object `fields` and show concrete element form (input, textarea, etc) based on  `fieldType`.

Now issue is to build dynamically a table base on type `fieldType: "table"`. When there is `sourceUrl` where data should be loaded and displaied.

I do this in *ngFor directly in template.

How to show table?

I think it is a bad idea to call http `sourceUrl` from template in loop ngfor.

Updated:

```
<div class="document-block">
    <div class="document-block__title">{{ documentBlock.title }}</div>
    <div class="document-block__fields">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let field of documentBlock.fields">
            <div class="document-block__fields__field">
                <app-field [fieldDefinition]="field"></app-field>
            </div>
        </ng-container>
    </div>
    <div class="document-block__nested-blocks">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let documentBlock of documentBlock?.blocks">
            <app-document-form [documentBlock]="documentBlock"></app-document-form>
        </ng-container>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this template I get each field and build concrete filed type (input, textarea):

```
<app-field [fieldDefinition]="field"></app-field>
```

Comment: can you showcase what you have done with *ngFor, no one can tell where you are getting stuck without your code. also if it's just about showing a table the create table with *ngFor attribute it will do that for you.

Comment: Sure, I have updated question

Comment: I suppose app-field/app-document-form are child component where you want to write table and there only you are passing your ngfor data. where is that code? the table should be built there.

Comment: Yes, this component builds form fields or table with data. Data should be loaded by url and filled in table. All this works in ngFor

Comment: did you checked that component if it's getting data! also, show code in the child component I thing there you want the real help. have you build the table and it's not displaying or you want help with table creation??

Comment: I need help in architecrute of build table, should it be in loop or ni different component like componentTable that dinamically injected in template ? I dont know how to request http data in template in loop ngFor

Comment: see you don't need to create further loops just create a table inside child component, and do template binding according to your use rest angular will do it for you. check this [URL](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-example-table?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable%2Ftable.component.html)

Comment: Yes, but  response has no `fieldType: "table"` sometimes

Comment: You dont understan my question. I dont have data of table. I have just indicator `fieldType: "table"` and sourceUrl so, in loop I want to build this table dinamically

Comment: just use simple ngIf attribute to check fieldType == table that will do the trick you must be getting that data in there !! right?  also, check the same for sourceUrl with your required condition in the same line

Comment: Yes, I can check it using ngIf, but how to get data by sourceUrl from template and back data to template to build table?

Comment: call another method in component.ts when you receive data and take URL from these and simply call them using for/map and then append the result to your current object with new key name, but why don't your call data  in api insted of a url?

Comment: So, you suggest to create a component TableComponent that accepts Input url srouce and contains method inside to load data and return to template, right?

Comment: Must it be async call?

Comment: No not another component but inside the same component create another getdatafromurl method call it on success of your current data get method.in getdatafromurl method map the current array and inside map make your http call for URL and on success append its result to copy of your current array. And use this copyarray in html as it will have data from url.

Comment: Could you share an sample when call http in which loop step? After all loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make components for each type. E.g.: `TableComponent` and `InputComponent`.
- Check what component to use by checking the `fieldType`
- pass the component the information it needs to render the element ( in your table this would be the `sourceUrl`, with which the `TableComponent` would know what to do )

**an example in code**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let field of documentBlock.fields">
    <app-table *ngIf='field.fieldType === "table"' [details]='field'></app-table>
    <app-input *ngIf='field.fieldType === "input"' [details]='field'></app-input>
</ng-container>
```

**Note:** You could refactor the list of if-statements in a separate component and decide what component is appropriate there. You would be implementing something very much like a [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) in that scenario.

**Extra: table.component.ts**

The `TableComponent` would look something like this. Be aware that there is a little time until the http-request completes. So you might want to use dummy-data until then or hide the component with *ngIf in your template.

Http-requests are usually asynchronous (in angular they are observables).

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './table.component.css' ]
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
  // you can set data to null and do an *ngIf check in the template or set some dummy data until it is loaded.
  data = null;
  @Input() details;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get( this.details.sourceUrl )
    .subscribe( response => {
      this.data = response;
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, when to call http method to get data in `app-table` component? Could you share an sample, is it async?

Comment: @Jony I dropped in a quick version of the `app-table` component for you.

Comment: will the loop wait response from http, or Angular renders template then async data comes to template?

Comment: @Jony The loop won't wait, it will just create the components. But the data will be displayed in the component only after the data is available from the http-request. You could put a placeholder object in `data` until then or hide the table-components content inside the table-component template using `*ngIf='data'`.